# How to determine how to restart an application

Tags: linux

I have an application that is topping at 190% cpu usage and I'd like to get it restarted.  The problem is, I'm not sure how I should restart it.  I've looked it `/etc/init.d` and I don't see anything there that's related to it.  Where else should I look?  in `top` it's called `PNetTNetServer.`

I can kill it, it's just once I kill it I need to make sure it starts back up again.

Comment: Is there no documentation or a support line you can call ?

Comment: There has to be a way to figure this out.  The server guy isn't here, so I can't ask him.

Comment: Maybe this is started by something else rather than directly? Look at the process in forest mode and see what it's parent is? `ps auxwf | less -S` should make it readable.

Answer (score 5):

You can use ps or top to find the process id (pid).  Once you know the pid you can find out a lot of information about the process by looking in the /proc/ directory.  That directory will contain the command line used to invoke it (cmdline), the executable (exe), the working directory (cwd) and a lot of other information.  From there you should be able to figure out what is running.  Using ps you can find the parent process id and use the same process (no pun intended) to figure out the details of what called it and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Top is the right place to start since it gives you an overview of all processes that are running. Additionally once you learn the pid (process id) you can give that to top for more insight into the process itself. `top -p [the pid of the process]`.

Additionally as already mentioned you could issue something like `ps aux | grep PNetTNetServer` that will give you more detail on the process.

Stopping it can be done in various ways but specifically with the command `kill` but as you mention you should look for ways to shut down that process without issuing kill. On top of that, understanding what that process is doing is probably more important than shutting it down.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to kill it with "kill -HUP " but I give no warranty, it will restart normally.